# use jquery to get index of element in parsed html result set

Tags: jquery

it appears that

```
$(html).find('*').index('#theID');
```

yields -1 whereas

```
$(html).find('*').each(function(ind){if(this.id=='theID') alert('found! @'+ind) } );
```

does work (alerting 229)

I am using **Windows 7** with **IE 8** and **jquery 1.6.1**

My question is, why doesn't the first one work?  Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't use IE9?

Comment: I'd recommend that you try it out, it supports some CSS3 specs and it's JavaScript engine is remarkably faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the jQuery documentation for [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/). The API for a string argument is as follows (italic emphasis added):

> **selector** A selector representing a jQuery collection *in which to look
>   for an element*.
>
> ...
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the *position of the original element* relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.

To do what you are trying to do requires you to pass an element (or jQuery object) as the argument, not a string. Therefore, something like this should do what you want:

<del>`$(html).find("*").index($("#theID", html));`</del>

**Edit** (see comments)

Since `html` is a string, creating 2 different jQuery objects from that string is going to cause problems. To solve that, you can pass it into jQuery once:

```
var $html = $(html);
$html.find("*").index($html.find("#theID"));
```

---

The documentation for this form of `index` states the following:

> **element** The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to
>   look for.
>
> ...
>
> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   *position of the passed element* relative to the original collection.

Comment: Since `html` is a string, it will create two different trees.  The `theID` element you create to search for won't be the same one in the tree you are actually traversing.

Comment: @Dennis - That's a great point. I never even considered that. Thanks.

Comment: great, the latter code example works.  I had the weird notion that .index(selector) used the selector on the set of elements.  HOW SILLY OF ME. :-P.  I think there is a slight typo in that it should be var html, not var $html.

Comment: @user420667 - No, `$html` was intentional, since you already have a variable named `html`. When you pass something into jQuery and store a reference to the resulting jQuery object, prefixing the new identifier with a `$` symbol can simply help to remind you that you're now dealing with a jQuery object. It has no special meaning.

Comment: oh, ok, maybe it's just an ie8 thing but it doesn't like it.  Thanks for the other help though.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Not sure why IE8 would have a problem with that, but it's perfectly safe to rename `$html` to anything you like!

Comment: actually, i was doing var $theHtml = $(html), then it complained about theHtml.find('.... since it didn't know what theHtml was.... but that sort of defeats the purpose of the $ in the first place.

Comment: @user420667 - Sorry! I've just realised why you may be having problems... typo on my behalf, I missed the `$` from the start of the identifiers on the second line. Ooops. Fixed it in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `index` method passing a `selector` on a matched set of DOM elements it looks for the first element among the object's matched elements which also matches this selector and is located returning its index.

Mostly like `thisID` is not the first element in `$(html).find('*')` collection that is why you are get `-1`.

In the below working demo I have `theID` as the first element in the body and I am getting the index as `0`.

```
var html = $('body');
alert($(html).find('*').index('#theID'));//Returns 0 index
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y33xu/)**